# c# code re-usability

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, forms, stored-procedures

I am creating a form. On the same form I'm displaying the current data also in gridview. I'm using stored procedures for insert and select.

Every time the page loads it inserts a blank row even without submit.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

this is gridview control

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="userID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="userID" HeaderText="userID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="userID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="userFname" HeaderText="userFname" SortExpression="userFname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="userLName" HeaderText="userLName" SortExpression="userLName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="userMoNo" HeaderText="userMoNo" SortExpression="userMoNo" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="userEmail" HeaderText="userEmail" SortExpression="userEmail" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="userCity" HeaderText="userCity" SortExpression="userCity" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="userArea" HeaderText="userArea" SortExpression="userArea" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="userType" HeaderText="userType" SortExpression="userType" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="userStatus" HeaderText="userStatus" SortExpression="userStatus" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="strOwner" HeaderText="strOwner" SortExpression="strOwner" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="db_tstamp" HeaderText="db_tstamp" SortExpression="db_tstamp" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IBS_3 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_users]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

this is codebehind

```
    using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace IBS3.admin
{
    public partial class add_user : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IBS_3"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsUser", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("userFName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtFName.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("userLName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtLName.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("userMoNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtMoNo.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("userEmail", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("userCity", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCity.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("userArea", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtArea.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("userType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUserType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("userStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtStatus.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@strOwner", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = User.Identity.Name;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@db_tstamp", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Now;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is insert procedure

```
    USE [IBS_3]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spInsUser]    Script Date: 02-26-2017 15:46:07 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsUser]
(
    @userFname nvarchar(50),
    @userLName nvarchar(50),
    @userMoNo nvarchar(50),
    @userEmail nvarchar(50),
    @userCity nvarchar(50),
    @userArea nvarchar(50),
    @userType nvarchar(50),
    @userStatus nvarchar(50),
    @strOwner nvarchar(50),
    @db_tstamp datetime2
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
INSERT INTO [tbl_users] ([userFname], [userLName], [userMoNo], [userEmail], [userCity], [userArea], [userType], [userStatus], [strOwner], [db_tstamp]) VALUES (@userFname, @userLName, @userMoNo, @userEmail, @userCity, @userArea, @userType, @userStatus, @strOwner, @db_tstamp);

SELECT userID, userFname, userLName, userMoNo, userEmail, userCity, userArea, userType, userStatus, strOwner, db_tstamp FROM tbl_users WHERE (userID = SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

this is select procedure

```
    USE [IBS_3]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spSelUser]    Script Date: 02-26-2017 15:47:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSelUser]
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT        userID, userFname, userLName, userMoNo, userEmail, userCity, userArea, userType, userStatus, strOwner, db_tstamp
FROM            tbl_users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you added your data insert logic in `Page_Load` what it does is when ever page loads first it runs every method or logic in it then it runs the rest of the page so you should not place your insert logic in `Page_Load`

you should create a class

```
private void insertuser()
{

string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IBS_3"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsUser", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("userFName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtFName.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("userLName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtLName.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("userMoNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtMoNo.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("userEmail", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("userCity", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCity.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("userArea", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtArea.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("userType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUserType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("userStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtStatus.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@strOwner", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = User.Identity.Name;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@db_tstamp", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Now;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
}
```

and on submit event call `insertuser();`

Comment: you can accept my answer if you dont know how check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work